# 14.04 - Failed to load session - Tried all other suggestions

Tags: 14.04, gnome, session

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so sorry if I mess something up.  But I turned my computer off like normal and when I turned it on the next day, anytime I enter my password, I get the error "Failed to Load Session" in red words above the little password box.

Google showed a bunch of different answers for this, including:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
```

All of these gave me an error message and didn't work.  I also tried pressing shift while restarting and selecting an older install but that didn't work either.

I'm posting this after booting from disk, I'm going to try to post the error messages from my tablet, but I stink at writing with it, so I'm not positive it will work.

Comment: If you have a "guest" account, can you log into it? Use the up/down arrow keys at the login prompt to scroll through the list of available usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my goodness, I'm so sorry! I found my own answer!  I assumed that the code above needed to be entered after booting into the recovery mode which was giving me the errors.  I was doing more research and found the Ctrl+Alt+F1 on the log in screen to go to the terminal thing.  This worked!